# jquery $.download truncates query parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an application that uses `$.download` to hit a nodejs api endpoint. 
The api expects values in req.query object.

My download implementation :

```
var url = "<%= Rails.application.config.default_api_urls %>forecast_inventory?alpha=0.3&beta=0.3&gamma=0.5&store_id="+$.cookie("store_id")+"&from=2016-02-26&to="+to_date+"&u=.csv" 
 console.log(url);
 $.download(url,'filename=mySpreadsheet&format=csv');
```

the output of console.log is :

```
https://myapiendpoint.io/v1/forecast_inventory?alpha=0.3&beta=0.3&gamma=0.5&store_id=12&from=2016-02-26&to=11-8-2016&u=.csv
```

but the request sent as recorded by browser debugger is:

```
Request URL:https://api-dev.faasos.io/v1/forecast_inventory?filename=mySpreadsheet&format=csv
Request Method:GET
```

The same method works fine if values are passed for req.params object.
How can I get the req.query values ??
Does `$.download()` truncate all query params passed ??

Comment: You should post the source for `$.download()`

Comment: Looks like `download` truncates parameters if you add your own?

Comment: @DaveNewton yes . but the api requires these values from the client end.

Comment: As @mscdex says - where did you get `$.download` from - it's not standard jQuery.  It may have the second param as "query string parameters" if the first param is "url", and therefore (not unreasonably) strip off any already supplied.  If you need to pass all those params, just pass them in the second argument?

Comment: Have you tried specifying ALL of the url parameters in the second parameter of the `$.download()` call?

Comment: Try moving your parameters into the $.download function... I think what's happening is your defined parameter is overwriting everything after the ?... So if you do $.download(url,'filename=mySpreadsheet&format=csv&alpha=0.3&beta...." it will probably work.

Comment: @mscdex could you please elaborate what do you mean by source of $.download() ?

its a function called on click of a button from simple html page

Comment: @SaleemAhmed I understand they're required. I'm saying whatever `$.download` is is stripping them, hence we need to know what `$.download` is.